# Express.js Routing: Wildcard/Search function

Tags: node.js, express

So one of my routes in my express app has you search for a contact. (/contact).
It goes off of the req.query to pull the information to search.

However, I'd like to add an option for /contact/:contact_id in case the user doesn't need to search for it. It's a lot easier than adding contact_id to the parameters for the end user if they already know the contact_id.

Can I have both a /contact and /contact/:contact_id and have them work properly? Or do I need to make /contact/:contact_id and add in an if statement to check if they have the contact id already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both `/contact` and `/contact/:contact_id` routes and the order in which you declare the routes do not matter.